# Close current session for user Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tracker

How I can close current session for user?

I use this package: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker

I can get current session:

```
$visitor = Tracker::currentSession();
```

But how I can force close for user this session?
Example: I have button "terminate current session" and when I submit, I need terminate current session. How I can do it?

Comment: You can do it through default Laravel session handling mechanism

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Please do it

Comment: Do you want to do this from admin panel or just to add a button on user panel for logout?

Comment: @mustafa.akcoban I want do table for user, where I want show: Where I want show to them:

Device (Mac, Phone, Tablet.. other),
Browser(Chrome, Safari, Opera .. etc),
Last Activity,
Date, when session will be closed,
IP,
Button for terminate certain session and button for terminate all sessions.